# Excel Macro for Updating log

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create a macro where I take what I have in a master file that is constantly being updating on the last row and placing this into a separate log file.

I would only like to copy specific cells from the last row of the original and paste them into the log file, i've gotten close I believe but need help with the following areas:

1. Selection of the specific columns in the last row
2. How to not have the log file open or activated at any point for this to happen when the Macro is run.

I apologize if this question has been answered but I can't seem to curate all the information I am finding online to an applicable solution. Here is the macro I have thus far...

```
' copy2 Macro
'
Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Select
Selection.EntireRow.copy
Windows("Daily Referral Log.xlsx").Activate
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying the log is a different workbook or a different worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to open the log workbook and paste the last row from a data file into it.

I think this is what you're looking for.

Please let me know if you need something else.

> How to not have the log file open or activated at any point for this to happen when the Macro is run.

Regarding this line, I think I am understanding you right.

You don't want to have to open it yourself manually; you want the code to do it.

If that's not what you mean, please let me know (you will have to lock the file for write access to modify it regardless).

```
Sub CopyLastRowToLog()

Dim ThisWb, wb As Workbook
Set ThisWb = ThisWorkbook
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("FileName and Path Goes Here") 'Edit This Line
On Error GoTo 0

'Basic Error Handling - Probably worth adding ReadOnly check but keeping code short
If wb Is Nothing Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Error Opening File")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Put the names of the sheets you're using below.
'The first 2 sheets should be the sheet you're copying from
'The second 2 sheets should be the sheet you're copying to
ThisWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Copy _
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

wb.Close (True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

To answer your first question, the file name looks weird:

```
Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\EYousefi\Desktop[Daily Referral Log.xlsx]Sheet1")
```

It should probably be:

```
Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\EYousefi\Desktop\Daily Referral Log.xlsx")
```

You don't need to specify the sheet there.

Secondly, to copy specific columns, you would want to change the copy line.
I added 2 new variables to make it easier to read:

```
'Get the last rows for the workbooks
Dim ThisWBLR, FinalWBLR

ThisWBLR = ThisWB.Sheets("Sheet5").UsedRange.Rows.Count
FinalWBLR = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count+1

ThisWb.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B" & ThisWBLR & ":D" & ThisWBLR).Copy _
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FinalWBLR)
```

You can also specify individual pieces of data one at a time if it is easier for you:

```
'Copy B to B
ThisWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B" & ThisWBLR).Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FinalWBLR)

'Copy C to C
ThisWB.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("C" & ThisWBLR).Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & FinalWBLR)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I used this but keep receiving a Error Opening File.. I am pretty unfamiliar with this specific portion of excel but heres what I changed from what you have above:

Comment: Sub CopyLastRowToLog()
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\EYousefi\Desktop\[Daily Referral Log.xlsx]Sheet1") 'Edit This Line
On Error GoTo 0


ThisWb.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet5").UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.copy _
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

wb.Close (True)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Comment: One final proposition is that the row i am copying, I would only like a handful of the columns not the entirety is that possible? Thank you SO MUCH for your HELP. Its very appreciated. @user1274820

Comment: I edited the original - sorry for the slow reply. Let me know what columns you want to copy and I can write additional code. Basically you can just enter the ranges you need and the ranges where you want to paste. I showed an example for B-D, but you can specify which range you want to copy and where you want to paste it on each line

Comment: Works Perfectly!! The individual pieces one at a time is what I ended up using as the other wasn't showing any information. Thanks a million @user1274820

Comment: This was working for and I haven't changed anything, and all of a sudden its not copying the information anymore. It is still running as before, and you see it opening and closing the log its pointed to, but its not actually copying the information from the rows over.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what part it could be, because its finding opening and closing the file fine, just the copying part is not happening @user1274820

Comment: Excel's copy function uses the clipboard, so maybe you have another application opening that is inhibiting the use of it? You can try `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FinalWBLR & ":D" & ThisWBLR).Value = ThisWb.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B" & ThisWBLR & ":D" & ThisWBLR).Value` I'm not 100%, but you may need to individually copy the values one at a time instead of doing it by value if you try it this way. A better alternative is making sure you are not blocking the clipboard IMO but there are workarounds if you can't use the copy function.

Comment: I didn't seem to find a way to use the line you provided above. I also checked my clipboard and its empty with it still not performing the function. have 5 lines after that are the same except with adjustments to which cells are being copied, but below is the code I have:
`ThisWBLR = ThisWb.Sheets("Patient List").UsedRange.Rows.Count
FinalWBLR = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

ThisWb.Sheets("Patient List").Range("B" & ThisWBLR).copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & FinalWBLR)`


@user1274820